# Is it safe to delete the journal file of mongodb?

Tags: linux, mongodb, disk

If I delete the 3.1G journal file, `sudo service mongodb restart` will fail. However, this file is taking too much space. How can I solve this problem? How can I remove it?

```
bash$ du -sh /var/lib/mongodb/*
4.0K    _tmp
65M auction_development.0
128M    auction_development.1
17M auction_development.ns
3.1G    journal
4.0K    mongod.lock
```

Answer (score 76, accepted):

TL;DR: You have two options. Use the `--smallfiles` startup option when starting MongoDB to [limit the size of the journal files](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/journaling/#journal-files) to 128MB, or turn off journalling using the `--nojournal` option. Using `--nojournal` in production is usually a bad idea, and it often makes sense to use different write concerns also in development so you don't have different code in dev and prod.

**The long answer**:
No, deleting the journal file isn't safe. The idea of journalling is this:

A write comes in. Now, to make that write persistent (and the database durable), the write must somehow go to the disk.

Unfortunately, writes to the disk take eons [compared to writes to the RAM](https://gist.github.com/hellerbarde/2843375), so the database is in a dilemma: not writing to the disk is risky, because an unexpected shutdown would cause data loss. But writing to the disk for every single write operation will decrease the database's performance so badly that it becomes unusable for practical purposes.

Now instead of writing to the data files themselves, and instead of doing it for every request, the database will simply append to a journal file where it stores all the operations that haven't been committed to the actual data files yet. This is a lot faster, because the file is already 'hot' since it's read and written to all the time, and it's only one file, not a bunch of files, and lastly, because it writes all pending operations in a batch every 100ms by default. Deleting this file in the middle of something wreaks havoc.

Comment: Information answer - is it possible to clear the journal files though? To free up space?

Comment: @wmock Only if you are adding the `smallfiles` option in (Mitjas answer)[http://stackoverflow.com/a/25516871/1318694] and have cleanly stopped the database before removal. The journal files will be recreated if missing every time the database starts up. The `smallfiles` option changes how large those files are.

Comment: I just wonder what's the rationale for having a 3 gig journal file by default. Do they expect a usual user will modify 3 gigs of data per 100 ms?

Comment: Journal files are *append only*, so they are not deleted or emptied every 100ms. They are rotated once they reach 1gig of size, and will be deleted once they are no longer required (ie, when all changes have been applied). That introduces another level of complexity where the durability thread needs to make *sure* there is no pending write, so it's possible for two to three files to coexist. See http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/journaling/#journal-files

Answer (score 75):

As explained in mnemosyn's answer, journaling is essential to the storage engines. Luckily, it can be controlled to some extent. The following was written for the **MMAPv1** storage engine, which was the default until MongoDB 3.2. Then, **WiredTiger** became the engine of choice, to which more information can be found at the bottom of this answer.

### MMAPv1

#### MongoDB < 2.6 (Non-YAML Config)

For our development server, we used the following procedure:

```
cp -p /etc/mongodb.conf /etc/mongodb.conf.orig
vi /etc/mongodb.conf
```

Now, insert

```
smallfiles=true
```

into the mongodb.conf, then save. *smallfiles* limits the journal file to 128MB.

```
service mongodb stop
rm -rf /var/lib/mongodb/journal/*
service mongodb start
```

#### MongoDB >= 2.6 (YAML Config)

If you're using MMAPv1 with the [YAML config style](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/configuration-options/#storage-mmapv1-options), use the same step to backup the config as above, but into the

```
  mmapv1:
```

config block, insert

```
    smallFiles: true
```

. Afterwards, proceed as above, restarting the server whilst removing the journals.

### WiredTiger (MongoDB >=3.0, default since 3.2)

On development machines, journal files under WiredTiger should be somewhat smaller by default than under MMAPv1, as [journal compression](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/configuration-options/#storage.wiredTiger.engineConfig.journalCompressor) is enabled by default. According to [the documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/core/journaling/), "WiredTiger journal files for MongoDB have a maximum size limit of approximately 100 MB". It will "create checkpoints (i.e. write the snapshot data to disk) at intervals of 60 seconds or 2 gigabytes of journal data."

Thus, if you're only running a low amount of requests (with little data to change) on your database, the journal files using WiredTiger should not exceed a low multiple of 100 MB. The size of the journal files seems not to be configurable, however.

Comment: The configuration file format changed in version 2.6 to YAML. See: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/#storage.mmapv1.smallFiles

Comment: Thanks @Skarllot for pointing this out. As I'm no longer into MongoDB, I would be grateful if someone extended my answer by a section for version 2.6.

Comment: I updated the answer to reflect YAML and WiredTiger.

Comment: Is there a way to limit the number of journal files if we have deployed a RAID 10 cluster with limited space allocated for journal files ?

Answer (score 10):

`mongodb` has evolved since. Now its [v3.4.1 stable](https://www.mongodb.com/download-center#community).
I am on [v3.2](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/configuration-options/) here's how:
uncomment `# mmapv1:` so it looks like:

```
  mmapv1:
    smallFiles: true
```

if you have a different version look for `storage Options` on the `reference/configuration-options` page.

don't forget to empty the `journal`

```
sudo service mongodb stop
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/mongodb/journal/*
sudo service mongodb start
```