# How could I change the location of journal files

Tags: mongodb

It seems the journal files still sotred at `/var/lib/mongodb/journal` even I pointed the location to /workspace/datastore

How could I save journal files in other places Because the root disk is almose full.

```
    ls
    prealloc.0  prealloc.1  prealloc.2
    pwd 
    /var/lib/mongodb/journal



systemLog:
    destination: file
    path: "/var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log"
    quiet: false
    logAppend: true
net:
    port: 27017
    bindIp: 0.0.0.0

storage:
    dbPath: /workspace/datastore
    engine: wiredTiger
```

Comment: This belongs on [dba.stackexhange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com) which is where you go when you want to ask questions about database configuration. Also says so in the tag summary [tag:mongo]. StackOverflow is for programming based questions only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/xcBQxO3UxIM)

> You can create a symbolic link to point the journal directory at a different file-system / block device.

More details is [Mongodb Journal](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/journaling/#journal-directory).

Another option is limiting the size of Journal file, here is one discussion

[Is it safe to delete the journal file of mongodb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19533019/is-it-safe-to-delete-the-journal-file-of-mongodb)