# Cleanup of Mongo journal file

Tags: mongodb, journal, journaling

Is there a way to reset the journal file. Will it have any implications ?

Right now i have a journal file of 2GB which is occupying lot of space in ec2.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You should stop the mongodb first:

```
service mongodb stop
rm -rf /var/lib/mongodb/journal
service mongodb start
```

**Additional hint:** you could limit the journal to 128MB by adding `smallfiles=true` to the config file `/etc/mongodb.conf`.

Solution taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25516871) and tested on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Thanks man. I realized it after some googling. Nevertheless, thanks a lot of pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

No need to restart mongod service - this is not good solution sometime.
There is more simple solution if you just want to cleanup the single log file:

```
echo '' > /var/lib/mongodb/journal.log
```

Comment: That cannot be right. `/var/lib/mongodb/journal` is a directory.

Comment: Original question was about a file, not about directory.
So, i assume /var/lib/mongodb/journal this is a path to file.
I just based my answer on previous question path - but answered original question